# What is this type of construction/phrase called? One set is part of a group, but the whole group is not a set

Tags: single-word-requests

The general idea is

> One set is part of a group, but the whole group is not a set

This might be kind of vague but I don't have a better example right now on this other than...

> All revolutionaries are terrorists, but not all terrorists are revolutionaries.

Comment: This sometimes occurs in connection with *false syllogisms*.

Comment: Apparently, [only 10% of cells on your “human” body are human anyway, the rest are microbial](https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/were-only-10-human-according-to-who/). So from the statistical perspective, arguably none of us are "truly" human.

Comment: This is not a question concerning language, but logic and belongs to philosphy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as Roger says, it is not a question **directly** concerning language, but logic /set theory and belongs to philosphy / maths.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is like saying :

> All cats are mammals, but not all mammals are cats

As you said, we are talking about **sets**, one set being an element, or member, of the other.

It is described on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)#Notation_and_terminology) :

> The relation "*is an element of*", also called set **membership**, is denoted by the symbol "*∈*".

---

By the way, all revolutionaries are not terrorists, cf Gandhi.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to an [association fallacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy):

> - an inductive informal fallacy of the type hasty generalization or red herring which asserts that qualities of one thing are inherently qualities of another, merely by an irrelevant association.
> - The two types are sometimes referred to as guilt by association and honor by association. Association fallacies are a special case of red herring, and can be based on an appeal to emotion.
>
> A syllogistic example of ***guilt by association:***
>
> - John is a con artist. John has black hair. Therefore, all people with black hair are con artists.
>
> The logical inverse of "guilt by association" is ***honor by association*** where one claims that someone or something must be reputable because of the people or organizations that are related to it or otherwise support it. For example:
>
> - Citizens of Country X won more Nobel Prizes, gold medals, and literary awards than citizens of Country Y. Therefore, a citizen of Country X is superior to a citizen of Country Y.

(Wikipedia)